# Value does not fall within the expected range in SharePoint

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

Currently I have scenario as my current production SharePoint server version is 2010 and we have developed an front end using MVC.

Now we have migrated our SharePoint server 2010 to SharePoint 2013.

As on development environment we are able to connect to migrated SharePoint 2013 from our MVC front end application and ran our QA very smoothly.

Now when we got the UAT environment with the same above scenario i.e. we got SharePoint 2010 server that is being migrated to SharePoint 2013. When we connect using same code base by changing only URL's, I am getting the subjected error at clientContext.ExecuteQuery().

I googled a lot and found couple of answers i.e. http://blog.vanmeeuwen-online.nl/2012/07/value-does-not-fall-within-expected.html and did the same configuration mentioned in this blog; but unfortunately the same solution does not work for us.

Please help me is there any other solutions available for this error.

Thanks,
Vijay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer to my question above!
The issue is something when I was testing my application the application created in development environment of SharePoint is the single instance only that doesn't have any subsites included. Hence the reason I was able to run very smoothly.

And now the scenario in my UAT, the application which was migrated from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013 has got site collections and subsites within the main root site.

And when we connect to the SharePoint using CSOM object we need to supply the FolderServerRelativeUrl path pointing to subsite only e.g. /testsite/sites/subsites, then path should pointing to /sites/subsites.

Thanks,
Vijay

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing the same scenario in dev and in UAT.
Usually you get errors because of discrepancy in permissions.
Review the permission/accounts/js/css checked-out.
This is pain men.